# Solving the logarithmic rational equation

Tags: functions, logarithms, closed-form, rational-functions

I'm wondering there exist the way to solve the equation form of:

$$
\log f(x) + g(x) = c
$$

where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are rational functions, $c$ is a constant.

Is there any general(in closed form) way to solve the equation above?

Comment: This looks like a job for Lambert-W man!

Comment: I've tried Lambert W-function already, but since $z$ in Lambert W cannot be represented in constant (only in function of $x$, form of $z(x)$), it is impossible to using Lambert W-function to solve the equation. But thankful comment though! Have a good day Marty!

Comment: sometimes it is useful to look at derivatives of such functions and try to solve the coreesponding differential equations.  Furthermore the Lagrange inversion theorem may be worth to look at

Comment: What are you actually trying to solve for?